# Get data on port 80 on non-dedicated server

Tags: php, apache

I have a hardware which send Formatted data to to specific IP & PORT and i have a **non-dedicated** server and the host admin don't allow to use `fsockopen()` and other socket function.
I need to get this data and save to database. How can i use port 80 for this purpose?

Extra information:
1-The hardware send some data to server each 10 seconds with my defined format and i can change it as i want:

```
START=string*value1*value2*.....*valueN*END
```

2-Open Ports on my server:

```
21/tcp   ftp
25/tcp   smtp
80/tcp   http    
110/tcp  pop3    
143/tcp  imap    
443/tcp  https    
465/tcp  smtps
```

Comment: Does the hardware send raw data or does it make a proper http request?

Comment: If your formatted text is not limited to one line, you can connect to 80 and make an HTTP request:`HTTP/1.1 /path/to/page?value=...\r\nHost: host\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: @Joni It can send both way with socket protocol and Http

Comment: @Passerby could you please give some more information?

Comment: What kind of HTTP requests can it send? IN particular, can it send the Host: header?

Comment: @osyan An HTTP Request is no more than connecting to 80 and send a formatted text. And the formatted text can be as simple as [containing only one request line and one Host header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_request#Client_request). And in the request line you can stuff info into [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). E.g. `GET /page.php?val1=1&val2=2 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: host\r\n\r\n`, and in `page.php` you can extra info like `$_GET["val1"]`, `$_GET["val2"]`.